# Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response

Tags: spring-integration, spring-rest

Well, I am trying to consume REST webservice using RestTemplate in Spring.
The service returns a JSON with list of objects in it as below.

```
[
  {
    "name": "123",
    "ids": {
      "y": 36.41666667,
      "x": 39.58333333,
      "z": 12
    },
    "ip": "10.219.90.12",
    "rate": 67.5,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "123",
    "ids": {
      "y": 72.5,
      "x": 15.16666667,
      "z": 12
    },
    "ip": "10.219.90.13",
    "rate": 67.5,
    "aarid": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "123",
    "ids": {
      "y": 0,
      "x": 14.33333333,
      "z": 12
    },
    "ip": "10.219.90.14",
    "rate": 67.5,
    "id": 3
  }]
```

I have a POJO defined as below for this JSON.

```
public class Data {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("ip")
    private String ip;
    @JsonProperty("rate")
    private Double rate;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty("ids")
    private Ids ids;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }
    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }
    public Double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }
    public void setRate(Double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Ids getIds() {
        return ids;
    }
    public void setIds(Ids ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
}


public class Ids {

    private Double x;

    private Double y;

    private Double z;

    public void setX(Double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(Double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setZ(Double z) {
        this.z = z;
    }

    public Double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public Double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Double getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AARPosition [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", z=" + z + "]";
    }

}
```

I try to consume the service with following code:

```
ResponseEntity<List<Data>> responseEntity = aarRestClient.exchange("http://123.11.25.333/v1/data",
                HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Data>>() {    });
```

I am passing null into entity above, even if I create entity and try, same results come up.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

ResponseEntity<List<Data>> responseEntity = aarRestClient.exchange("http://123.11.25.333/v1/data",
                HttpMethod.GET, entity , new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Data>>() { });
```

I have also tried with -

```
ResponseEntity<Data[]> responseEntity = aarRestClient.getForEntity("http://123.11.25.333:42317/v1/data", Data[].class);
```

But, no luck. I get below exception in all the cases.

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [Lcom.zebra.ala.rtlsclient.Data;] and content type [application/octet-stream]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:835) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:819) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:599) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:289) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.zebra.ala.rtlsclient.AARHealthHandler.monitorAARHealth(AARHealthHandler.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
```

Could please anyone help me out!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why using MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM? Are you working with files? Tried using  headers.setAccept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) ?

Comment: @Manuel: I have not tried with that, as it was complaining in exception as OCTET_STREAM. Will try and come back, thanks for getting back.

Comment: @Manuel:Tried with MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, but same results in exception.

Comment: Have you configured your message converters in your WebConfig?

Comment: No. I would like to tell you, below works:

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  List<Data> aarList= new ArrayList<Data>();
  
  String json = aarRestClient.getForObject("http://123.11.25.333:42317/v1/aar", String.class);
  
  aarList = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Data>>(){})`

What I understand is, this whole thing should be done by RestTemplate, when I pass the [new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Data>>() {    }] right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work with default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` because your server returns inappropriate `Content-Type` as `application/octet-stream`, where `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` supports only:

```
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    super(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, new MediaType("application", "*+json"));
}
```

You can provide your own instance of that converter with the customization via `setSupportedMediaTypes(List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes)`, but may be it really would be better to convince the server side to return correct JSON Content-Type...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks for your answer Artem!